# Salesforce login Organization behind proxy

Tags: python, salesforce

I am trying to connect to SalesForce using python and [Simple Salesforce](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce). My goal is to find something equivalent to the command line command - `sfdx force:auth:web:login -r $url` in python and obtain access token via custom domain. I run this command after specifying the proxy variables in command line by exporting http_proxy and https_proxy.

So far looking through the examples and going through the documentations I could not find anything that would be able to get me the token. Any guidance on this would be appreciated. I can call sdfx process but I was wondering if there was a way to do this via python.

Answer (score 0):

`simple_salesforce` does not provide most forms of OAuth authentication, like `force:auth:web:login`. The [three ways to log in](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#examples) with `simple_salesforce` are:

1. Provide your own access token, obtained through performing OAuth authentication elsewhere.
2. Perform a SOAP login by providing a username, password, and security token (or other required parameters depending on your org's specific configuration).
3. Use the JWT OAuth flow with a username and certificate.

Of the three, JWT is preferable when doing server-to-server integration, and SOAP login for interactive use at a console.

Comment: Is there a different library that could do this? I have tried the methods mentioned and they didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean? They certainly do work, but they don't provide OAuth capabilities. If your org is using specific strategies like IP whitelisting you may need to follow different instructions in the simple_salesforce docs.

Comment: [SalesforcePy](https://salesforcepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get_started.html) supports the username-password OAuth flow.

Comment: Whenever I try to get the token it returns none. Also all of these methods require client secret and key which I don't have. I was trying to get something to work with user ID and password. This is one of the methods with simple Salesforce but that requires the access token.

Comment: `simple_salesforce` _does_ provide username-password login. You'll need the _security token_, but that's not the same as an access token. Your security token is reset and emailed to you each time you reset your password.

Comment: Since the login in my organization is controlled via oauth I cannot reset the password and this wasn't sent to me when the account was initiated. Is there a way to get it from the portal?

Comment: What does "controlled via oauth" mean? Are you saying that your organization has mandatory SSO?

Comment: Yes so can't even login to portal without it.

Comment: Then `simple_salesforce` alone won't cut it. You'll have to implement OAuth outside of the  library (and create a Connected App to get a client secret and key), or use another library that supports OAuth login and gets you an access token, and then pass the access token to simple_salesforce. You won't be able to use the login option available in simple_salesforce itself.

Comment: See this SFSE question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/170673/using-salesforce-api-with-sso